# Been stuck on this for 3 weeks : txtOutput won't display logicalid.value. Returning undefined error. Relative link generator

Tags: javascript, html, forms, undefined, var

I've googled the crap out of this question, looked in books from the library, as well as asked friends, and haven't been able to figure this out. I am new to javascript, so please do bear with me. I'm adapting a form that spits out "Hi, 'name' !"

To one that spits out a relative link using the input from the user. In this case it is a logical id. So the user will enter their logical id, and the the generator spits out a link that looks like this:

```
<a href="#" bcmltype="link" logicalid="'logical id entered by user'">
```

Mine however keeps returning 'undefined', which seems to mean it is not accepting the user entry as a value.

I have defined the input type as a number, but am at a complete loss as to why it still remains undefined.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en-US">
 <head>
 <meta charset = "ASCII">
 <title>textBoxes.html</title>
 <script type = "text/javascript">
  // from textBoxes.html
  function sayHi(){
  var logicalid = document.getElementById("logicalid");
  var txtOutput = document.getElementById("txtOutput");
  var name = logicalid.value;
  txtOutput.value = "\x3ca href\x3d\x22\x23\x22 bcmltype\x3d\x22link\x22         logicalid\x3d\x22" + logicalid.value + "\x22\x3e"
  } // end sayHi
 </script>
 <link rel = "stylesheet"
   type = "text/css"
   href = "textBoxes.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>Relative link generator</h1>
 <form action = ">
  <fieldset>
  <label>Enter your logical id </label>
  <input type = "number"
    id = "logicalid" />
  <input type = "button"
    value = "click me"
    onclick = "sayHi()"/>
  <input type = "text"
    id = "txtOutput" />
  </fieldset>
 </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct, you just missed a `"` after the form's action

```
<form action = ">
```

should be

```
<form action = "">
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/15n7pn8r/

Comment: Thank you very much! I won't get those 3 weeks back, but this is by far the best experience I've had on SO!

Comment: Glad to help! I would advise you to use an editor with syntax highlight to quicky discover these kind of mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `"`to close the `action` of your `<form>`

```js
function sayHi(){
  var logicalid = document.getElementById("logicalid");
  var txtOutput = document.getElementById("txtOutput");
  var name = logicalid.value;
  console.log(name);
  txtOutput.value = "\x3ca href\x3d\x22\x23\x22 bcmltype\x3d\x22link\x22logicalid\x3d\x22" + logicalid.value + "\x22\x3e"
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en-US">
 <head>
 <meta charset = "ASCII">
 <title>textBoxes.html</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>Relative link generator</h1>
 <form action = "">
  <fieldset>
  <label>Enter your logical id </label>
  <input type="number" id="logicalid" />
  <input type = "button"
    value = "click me"
    onclick = "sayHi()"/>
  <input type = "text"
    id = "txtOutput" />
  </fieldset>
 </form>
 </body>
</html>
```